# How to parse string using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm pretty new to java, trying to find a way to do this better. Potentially using a regex.

```
String text = test.get(i).toString()
// text looks like this in string form:
// EnumOption[enumId=test,id=machine]

String checker = text.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(",")[1].split("=")[1];

// checker becomes machine
```

My goal is to parse that `text` string and just return back `machine`. Which is what I did in the code above.

But that looks ugly. I was wondering what kinda regex can be used here to make this a little better? Or maybe another suggestion?

Comment: For clarification: Do you want to get the string that is written behind `id=` regardless of the following string?

Comment: `String checker = text.replaceFirst("EnumOption\\[enumId=test,id=(.*)\\]", "$1");` but isn’t there a simpler option like `test.get(i).getId()`?

Comment: What’s `test`? As Holger said, can’t you get the object’s ID directly without going the detour via `toString()`?

Comment: @Holger, I 100% agree with you, but in Eclipse when I tried to do that. .getId() was not an option. I don't know much about java. I just assumed if Eclipse doesn't show it available, then it's not available.

Comment: test is a customTypedList, and I iterate through it, looping through each element. and each element is an enumOption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex' lookbehind:

```
(?<=\bid=)[^],]*
```

[See Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JQ3nVD/4).

```
(?<=     )            // Start matching only after what matches inside
    \bid=             // Match "\bid=" (= word boundary then "id="),
          [^],]*      // Match and keep the longest sequence without any ']' or ','
```

In Java, use it like this:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\bid=)[^],]*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("EnumOption[enumId=test,id=machine]");
    if (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
  }
}
```

This results in

```
machine
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you’re using the Polarion ALM API, you should use the `EnumOption`’s [`getId` method](https://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/javadoc/com/polarion/platform/persistence/spi/EnumOption.html#getId()) instead of deparsing and re-parsing the value via a string:

```
String id = test.get(i).getId();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the replace and split functions don't take the structure of the data into account.

If you want to use a regex, you can just use a capturing group without any lookarounds, where enum can be any value except a `]` and comma, and id can be any value except `]`.

The value of id will be in capture group 1.

```
\bEnumOption\[enumId=[^=,\]]+,id=([^\]]+)\]
```

**Explanation**

- `\bEnumOption` Match `EnumOption` preceded by a word boundary
- `\[enumId=` Match `[enumId=`
- `[^=,\]]+,` Match 1+ times any char except `=` `,` and `]`
- `id=` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\]]+` Match 1+ times any char except `]`
- `)\]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W9kpBP/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Ybz7Oh)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bEnumOption\\[enumId=[^=,\\]]+,id=([^\\]]+)\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("EnumOption[enumId=test,id=machine]");

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
machine
```

---

If there can be more comma separated values, you could also only match id making use of negated character classes `[^][]*` before and after matching id to stay inside the square bracket boundaries.

```
\bEnumOption\[[^][]*\bid=([^,\]]+)[^][]*\]
```

In Java

```
String regex = "\\bEnumOption\\[[^][]*\\bid=([^,\\]]+)[^][]*\\]";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3shH53/1)

Answer (score 0):

A regex can of course be used, but sometimes is less performant, less readable and more bug-prone.

I would advise you not use any regex that you did not come up with yourself, or at least understand completely.

PS: I think your solution is actually quite readable.

Here's another non-regex version:

```
String text = "EnumOption[enumId=test,id=machine]";
text = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);
```

Not doing you a favor, but the downvote hurt, so here you go:

```
String input = "EnumOption[enumId=test,id=machine]";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("EnumOption\\[enumId=(.+),id=(.+)\\]").matcher(input);
if(!matcher.matches()) {
  throw new RuntimeException("unexpected input: " + input);
}

System.out.println("enumId: " + matcher.group(1));
System.out.println("id: " + matcher.group(2));
```

Comment: When you talk about performance, I’m wondering why you are unnecessarily doing two `substring` operations instead of a single `text.substring(text.lastIndexOf('=') + 1, text.length() - 1)`

Comment: I did not mean to imply that my version is more performant. I usually optimize for readability and speed of implementation. It was more of a general comment.

Comment: So you think, doing two `substring` operations instead of one makes the code more readable?

Comment: Not really no. About as straightforward as the OP's own solution. Readable, easy to understand and step through with the debugger.

Comment: `int start = text.lastIndexOf("id="); int end = text.length() - 1; text = text.substring(start, end);` How is that not more readable that the two substrings?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire That is arguably even more readable. I feel very misunderstood. I was trying to say that any non-regex solution is often quicker to implement and easier to understand and maintain.